# open file by std::ifstream occasionaly fails on folder detected by FindFirstChangeNotification (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have an application that must monitor some folders (in Windows) to detect if a file was created in that folder (real use is to detect incoming FTP files).
If a file is detected , it is read, then deleted .
***Occasionally***, I get a file reading error on a file that was detected.

Question is: Why?

To simulate the error, I created a simple program to reproduce it:

```
std::vector<std::filesystem::path> watch;
void main()
{
  watch.push_back("D:\\test1"); //must exist
  watch.push_back("D:\\test2");
  watch_dir();
}
```

this example monitors 2 folders.

To simulate incoming files on the folder, another program copies files to that folder
continuously at configurable intervals (say 100 milliseconds).

To detect folder changes , WIN32 API functions FindFirstChangeNotification and WaitForMultipleObjects are used, based on this Microsoft example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications

detection function adapted from the example (Note: WaitForMultipleObjects blocks until a change is detected)

```
void watch_dir()
{
  HANDLE handle[2];
  memset(handle, 0, 2 * sizeof(HANDLE));

  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < watch.size(); idx++)
  {
    std::string str = watch.at(idx).string();
    LPTSTR path = (LPTSTR)str.c_str();
    std::cout << "watch path " << path << std::endl;

    handle[idx] = FindFirstChangeNotification(
      path,                          // directory to watch 
      FALSE,                         // do not watch subtree 
      FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME); // watch file name changes 

    if (handle[idx] == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
      assert(0);
      ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }
  }

  while (TRUE)
  {
    std::cout << "Waiting for notification..." << std::endl;

    DWORD wait_status = WaitForMultipleObjects(watch.size(), handle, FALSE, INFINITE);

    std::cout << "Directory " << watch.at(wait_status) << " changed" << std::endl;

    if (FindNextChangeNotification(handle[wait_status]) == FALSE)
    {
      assert(0);
      ExitProcess(GetLastError());
    }

    std::filesystem::path path = watch.at(wait_status);
    send_files_in_path(path);
  }
}
```

Once a change is detected by the function above, then all files in the folder are listed
and read, by these functions

```
void send_files_in_path(const std::filesystem::path& ftp_path)
{
  std::vector<std::filesystem::path> list = get_files(ftp_path);
  for (size_t idx = 0; idx < list.size(); idx++)
  {
    std::string buf;
    read_file(list.at(idx).string(), buf);

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::filesystem::remove(list.at(idx));
  }

}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//get_files
//get all ".txt" files inside a FTP folder
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

std::vector<std::filesystem::path> get_files(const std::filesystem::path& base_archive_path)
{
  std::vector<std::filesystem::path> list;
  try
  {
    for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(base_archive_path))
    {
      std::filesystem::path path = entry.path();
      if (!entry.is_regular_file())
      {
        continue;
      }
      std::string fname = entry.path().filename().string();
      size_t len = fname.size();
      size_t pos = len - 4;
      //check if last 4 characters are ".txt"
      if (fname.find(".txt", pos) == std::string::npos && fname.find(".TXT", pos) == std::string::npos)
      {
        continue;
      }

      SPDLOG_INFO("loading: " + entry.path().string());
      list.push_back(path);
    }//this path
  } //try

  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    SPDLOG_ERROR(e.what());
  }

  return list;
}
```

The function where the error happens is

```
int read_file(const std::string& fname, std::string& buf)
{
  std::ifstream ifs;
  std::ios_base::iostate mask = ifs.exceptions() | std::ios::failbit;
  ifs.exceptions(mask);

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
  std::cout << "opening : " << fname << std::endl;

  try
  {
    ifs.open(fname);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
      std::cout << "open fail: " << fname << std::endl;
      return -1;
    }
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << ifs.rdbuf();
  ifs.close();
  buf = ss.str();

  return 0;
}
```

the try/catch block, again, ***occasionally*** , is triggered with the error

> ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error

removing the try/catch block, and the open mask (just to try), then

```
ifs.is_open
```

fails.

A temporary solution was to detect the cases where the open() failed and repeat it.. which succeeds, because the file does exist.

Calling this with a small delay before the open call has the effect of reducing the open fails

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
ifs.open(fname);
```

But still would like to find out the reason for the occasional failure

Comment: Process Monitor, check the NTSTATUS of the failed open call. Could be antivirus or something locking the file...

Comment: Chances are, the files are probably still being written into the folder at the time you try to access them. `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` tells you when a file is created, not when its finished. Consider watching `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE` or `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` as well to detect the last time a given file is written to, resetting a timer on each write event, and then process the file once the timer elapses. Also, note that `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` includes file *deletions*, so make sure you are handling that possibility.

Comment: [std::ifstream::open](https://cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/open/#:~:text=Opens%20the%20file%20identified%20by%20argument%20filename%2C%20associating,it%20is%20already%20open%29%2C%20calling%20this%20function%20fails.)If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already open), calling this function fails. I suggest you could check if the file is locked when opened.

Comment: @jea Did you even understand the text you quoted? You *"- MSFT"* folks sure are a very special kind.

Comment: @RemyLebeau good catch, thanks! Yes, this could be a reason. I did a small test with FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, but the file open issue still happens. Will do more tests. No sure if FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE is only issued when the file is actually closed. And even if so, it could take some extra time (milliseconds) for the kernel to close the handle, from what I understand from Windows I/O internals. Yes, also aware that FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME includes deletions, but in this case, the event does not cause any problems (number of files to detect is zero)